# Apply a border to a padded block item without increasing size

Tags: css, border, padding

Is it possible to apply a border to the top of a block item whose dimensions are set by the content/padding without increasing the size?

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ONWXqm

HTML

```
<div class=“div1">Div 1</div>
<div class=“div2">Div 2</div>
```

CSS

```
.div1, .div2 {
  float: left;
  padding: 1em;
}
.div1 {
  background-color: red;
  border-top: 4px solid green;
}
.div2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: it would work if box-sizing had a valid value and if **boxes had an height set**

Comment: Like GCyrillus said, Box-Sizing was made specifically for this.

Comment: @GCyrillus Thanks, but the content gets moved down.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution: using calc()

```css
.div1, .div2, .div3 {
  float: left;
  padding: 1em; /* Using em */
}

.div1 {
  background-color: red;
  border-top: 4px solid green; /* Using px */
  box-sizing: border; /* does not work */
}

.div2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.div3 {
  background-color: yellow;
  border-top: 4px solid green; /* Using px */
  padding-top: calc(1em - 4px);
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  Div 1
</div>
<div class="div2">
  Div 2
</div>
<div class="div3">
  Div 3
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure...a box shadow:

```css
.div1,
.div2 {
  float: left;
  padding: 1em;
  /* Using em */
}
.div1 {
  background-color: red;
  box-shadow: 0 -4px 0px 0px green;
}
.div2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  Div 1
</div>
<div class="div2">
  Div 2
</div>
```

Or an inset version

```css
.div1,
.div2 {
  float: left;
  padding: 1em;
  /* Using em */
}
.div1 {
  background-color: red;
  box-shadow: inset 0 4px 0px 0px green;
}
.div2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  Div 1
</div>
<div class="div2">
  Div 2
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is solution using **pseudo-element** that will be contained within the element itself and placed on top of it (absolute position and larger z-index). **This solution will work in IE8 and later** and also in IE6 or IE7 using polyfills.

**Code with comments to help you understand:**

```
.div1 {
   position: relative; /* Contain the absolute positioned element */
   z-index: 1; /* This line isn't needed since it it set to 1 by default, but for the sake of this demo its here */
}

.div1:before {
   content: ""; /* Pseudo-elements must not be empty to display */
   position: absolute; /* Cut out the element from the standard document flow */
   display: block; /* Pseudo-elements are inline by default */
   z-index: 2; /* Larger value than its parent to display on top of it */

   top: 0; /* We will be simulation top border here */
   left: 0; /* If you are using box-sizing: border-box, you can instead set width: 100%. But this left: 0; right: 0; will work in both cases */
   right: 0;

   height: 4px; /* Size of the border */
   background-color: green; /* Make it visible for us humans */
   /* You can also use border-top instead of height & background-color */

}
```

**Actual code:**

```css
.div1,
.div2 {
  float: left;
  padding: 1em;
}

.div1 {
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.div1:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 4px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  Div 1
</div>
<div class="div2">
  Div 2
</div>
```